# Why use bzero over memset?

Tags: c, memset, systems-programming

In a Systems Programming class I took this previous semester, we had to implement a basic client/server in C.  When initializing the structs, like `sock_addr_in`, or char buffers (that we used to send data back and forth between client and server) the professor instructed us to only use `bzero` and not `memset` to initialize them.  He never explained why, and I'm curious if there is a valid reason for this?

I see here: http://fdiv.net/2009/01/14/memset-vs-bzero-ultimate-showdown that `bzero` is more efficient due to the fact that is only ever going to be zeroing memory, so it doesn't have to do any additional checking that `memset` may do.  That still doesn't necessarily seem like a reason to absolutely not use `memset` for zeroing memory though.

`bzero` is considered deprecated, and furthermore is a not a standard C function. According to the manual, `memset` is preferred over `bzero` for this reason.  So why would you want to still use `bzero` over `memset`?  Just for the efficiency gains, or is it something more?  Likewise, what are the benefits of `memset` over `bzero` that make it the de facto preferred option for newer programs?

Comment: seems like memset is more portable

Comment: "Why use bzero over memset?" - ***Don't.*** Memset is standard, bzero isn't.

Comment: my question is - why not use calloc in this case?

Comment: bzero is a BSDism(). memset() is ansi-c. nowadays, bzero() will probably be implemented as a macro. Do ask your professor to shave himself and read some books. *efficiency* is a bogus-argument. A syscall or context-switch can easily cost tens of thousands clock ticks, one pass over a buffer runs at bus speed. If you want to optimise network-programs: minimise the number of syscalls (by reading/writing larger chunks)

Comment: The idea that `memset` may be slightly less efficient because of "a bit more checking going" is definitely a case of premature optimization: whatever the gains that you might see from omitting a CPU instruction or two are not worth it when you can jeopardize portability of your code. `bzero` is obsolete, and that's enough reason not to use it.

Comment: Related: [bzero() & bcopy() versus memset() & memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330673/2157640)

Comment: Often, you can add an initializer ` = {0}` instead, and not call a function at all. This became easier when around the turn of the century C stopped requiring up-front declaration of local variables. Some _truly_ old paperware is still stuck deep in the previous century, though.

Comment: Did your professor ever end up giving you a reason?

Comment: @S.S.Anne no, but it most likely originated from a recommended book for the course he was influenced by, as mentioned in one of the answers below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097072/1428743

Comment: `explicit_bzero` or just `bzero`? This distinction matters a lot as far as best practices and general rules about whether you should use it instead of `memset` go.

Comment: Maybe you should look at what courses you take, if you are unable to ask questions to your teacher, to aid understanding. ;)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I don't see any reason to prefer `bzero` over `memset`.

`memset` is a standard C function while `bzero` has never been a C standard function. The rationale is probably because you can achieve exactly the same functionality using `memset` function.

Now regarding efficiency, compilers like `gcc` use builtin implementations for `memset` which switch to a particular implementation when a constant `0` is detected. Same for `glibc` when builtins are disabled.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.  I was pretty sure that `memset` should always be used in this case, but was confused as to why we weren't using it.  Thanks for clarifying, and reaffirming my thoughts.

Comment: I've had many problems with broken `bzero` implementations. On non-aligned arrays it used to overshoot the provided length and zero out a little more bytes. Never had such an issue after switching to `memset`.

Comment: Don't forget about `memset_s` which should be used if you want to ensure the compiler doesn't quietly optimize-away a call to "scrub" memory for some security-related purpose (such as blanking-out a region of memory that contained a sensitive piece of information such as a cleartext password).

Answer (score 72):

I'm guessing you used (or your teacher was influenced by) *UNIX Network Programming* by W. Richard Stevens.  He uses `bzero` frequently instead of `memset`, even in the most up-to-date edition.  The book is so popular, I think it's become an idiom in network programming which is why you still see it used.

I would stick with `memset` simply because `bzero` is deprecated and reduces portability.  I doubt you would see any real gains from using one over the other.

Comment: You would be correct.  We didn't have required textbooks for this course, but I just checked the syllabus again and _UNIX Network Programming_ is indeed listed as an optional resource.  Thanks.

Comment: It's actually worse than that. It was deprecated in POSIX.1-2001 and _removed_ in POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: Quoting page 8 of the third edition of _UNIX Network Programming_ by W. Richard Stevens - _Indeed, the author of TCPv3 made the mistake of swapping the second and third arguments to memset in 10 occurrences of the first printing. A C compiler cannot  catch this error because both occurrences are the same... it was an error, and could be avoided using bzero, because swapping the two arguments to bzero will always be caught by the C compiler if function prototypes are used._ However as paxdiablo pointed out, bzero is deprecated.

Comment: @AaronNewton, you should add that to [Michael’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17097978/119540) since it confirms what he said.

Comment: Re: reduces portability: it is profoundly trivial to polyfill, and what you get in exchange is reducing the needless potential for human error, which demands a chronic mental vigilance cost which could be better spent on noticing other logic problems.

Answer (score 63):

The one advantage that I think `bzero()` has over `memset()` for setting memory to zero is that there's a reduced chance of a mistake being made.

More than once I've come across a bug that looked like:

```
memset(someobject, size_of_object, 0);    // clear object
```

The compiler won't complain (though maybe cranking up some warning levels might on some compilers) and the effect will be that the memory isn't cleared. Because this doesn't trash the object - it just leaves it alone - there's a decent chance that the bug might not manifest into anything obvious.

The fact that `bzero()` isn't standard is a minor irritant. (FWIW, I wouldn't be surprised if most function calls in my programs are non-standard; in fact writing such functions is kind of my job).

In a comment to another answer here, Aaron Newton cited the following from Unix Network Programming, Volume 1, 3rd Edition by Stevens, et al., Section 1.2 (emphasis added):

> `bzero` is not an ANSI C function. It is derived from early Berkely
>   networking code. Nevertheless, we use it throughout the text, instead
>   of the ANSI C `memset` function, because `bzero` is easier to remember
>   (with only two arguments) than `memset` (with three arguments). Almost
>   every vendor that supports the sockets API also provides `bzero`, and
>   if not, we provide a macro definition in our `unp.h` header.
>
> Indeed, **the author of TCPv3 [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 3 - Stevens 1996] made the mistake of swapping the second
>   and third arguments to `memset` in 10 occurrences in the first
>   printing**. A C compiler cannot catch this error because both arguments
>   are of the same type. (Actually, the second argument is an `int` and
>   the third argument is `size_t`, which is typically an `unsigned int`,
>   but the values specified, 0 and 16, respectively, are still acceptable
>   for the other type of argument.) The call to `memset` still worked,
>   because only a few of the socket functions actually require that the
>   final 8 bytes of an Internet socket address structure be set to 0.
>   Nevertheless, it was an error, and one that could be avoided by using
>   `bzero`, because swapping the two arguments to `bzero` will always be
>   caught by the C compiler if function prototypes are used.

I also believe that the vast majority of calls to `memset()` are to zero memory, so why not use an API that is tailored to that use case?

A possible drawback to `bzero()` is that compilers might be more likely to optimize `memcpy()` because it's standard and so they might be written to recognize it. However, keep in mind that correct code is still better than incorrect code that's been optimized. In most cases, using `bzero()` will not cause a noticeable impact on your program's performance, and that `bzero()` can be a macro or inline function that expands to `memcpy()`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this might be a reasoning when working in a classroom setting like this was, so as to make it potentially less confusing for the students.  I don't think this was the case with my professor, however.  He was a very big RTFM teacher.  If you had a question that could be answered by the manual, he would pull up the man pages on the projector in class and show you.  He was very much about ingraining into everyone's minds that the manual is there to be read and answers most of your questions.  I'm thankful for this, as opposed to some other professors.

Comment: I think that this is an argument that can be made even outside the classroom - I've seen this bug in production code. It strikes me as an easy mistake to make. I'd also guess that the vast majority of `memset()` calls are simply to zero out a block of memory, which I think is another argument for `bzero()`.  What does the 'b' in `bzero()` stand for anyway?

Comment: +1.  That `memset` violates a common parameter ordering of "buffer, buffer_size" makes it particularly error-prone IMO.

Comment: In Pascal they avoid that by calling it "fillchar" and it takes a char. Most C/C++ compilers would pick that one up. Which makes me wonder why compilers don't say "you are passing a 32/64 bit pointer where a byte is expected" and kick you firmly in the compiler errors.

Comment: I guess the `b` in `bzero` comes from “buffer”, @MichaelBurr. But it can also be “binary” or “byte”.

Comment: It seems that this is indeed [the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset#comment51194513_17097072) to the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr what is the bug in the memset-example you supplied..? could you explain it?

Comment: @Gewure second and third argument are in wrong order; the quoted function call does exactly _nothing_

Comment: @PseudoPsyche There is a huge difference between spoon-feeding answers (instead of encouraging looking at the manual) and guiding programmers to a better interface that is less error-prone because it requires less vigilant remembering of arbitrary detail. Those only look superficially similar to an untrained eye, because they both approximately resemble a value of personal responsibility for checking the documentation.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche I both expect people to RTMF, thoroughly and carefully at that, but I also recognize that every interface irregularity and relevant possibility that a brain has to keep track of is a cost. In the case of `memset` case, the cognition to pass value-then-size instead of size-then-value when calling `memset` needs to be regularly used or rehearsed, which includes the cognition of always checking "wait am I using one of the exceptional functions?" before slipping into the more generally used and reinforced cognition flow of passing buffer-size-right-after-buffer-pointer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The b in `bzero` most likely stands for byte, which would mean "byte zero" -> "zero out a region in byte-sized indivisible increments"

Answer (score 5):

Have it any way you like. :-)

```
#ifndef bzero
#define bzero(d,n) memset((d),0,(n))
#endif
```

Note that:

1. The original `bzero` returns nothing, `memset` returns void pointer (`d`). This can be fixed by adding the typecast to void in the definition.
2. `#ifndef bzero` does not prevent you from hiding the original function even if it exists. It tests the existence of a macro. This may cause lots of confusion.
3. It’s impossible to create a function pointer to a macro. When using `bzero` via function pointers, this will not work.

Comment: What’s the problem with this, @Leeor? General antipathy for macros? Or you dislike the fact that this macro can be confused with the function (and possibly even hides it)?

Comment: @Palec, the latter. Hiding a redefinition as a macro can lead to so much confusion. Another programmer using this code thinks he's using one thing, and is unknowingly forced to use the other. That's a time bomb.

Comment: After giving it another thought, I agree that this is indeed a bad solution. Among other things I found a technical reason: When using `bzero` via function pointers, this will not work.

Comment: You really should have called your macro something other than `bzero`. This is an atrocity.

Comment: Flaws aside, this answer _is_ useful. At this moment, it's the first answer in the lot which proactively points out how trivially `bzero` can be defined - the macro given by the answer is an imperfect source-level polyfill, but a polyfill nonetheless, and you could follow this polyfilling approach to its logical improvement of defining a function named `bzero` on platforms that don't have it. (Similarly, you could decide to implement a function or macro with a different name, which also gets around `bzero` unportability, and this is the topmost answer to even come close to gesturing at this.)

Answer (score 4):

You probably *shouldn't* use `bzero`, it's not actually standard C, it was a POSIX thing.

And note that word "was" - it was *deprecated* in POSIX.1-2001 and *removed* in POSIX.1-2008 in deference to memset so you're better off using the standard C function.

Comment: What do you mean by standard C? You mean it is not found in standard C library?

Comment: @Koray, standard C means the ISO standard and, yes, `bzero` is not part of that.

Comment: No I mean, I do not know what you mean by any standard. Does ISO standard mean the standard C library? That comes with the language? The minimal library that we know it will be there?

Comment: @Koray, ISO is the standards organisation which is responsible for the C standard, the current one being C11, and earlier ones C99 and C89.  They lay down the rules that an implementation must follow in order to be considered C. So yes, if the standard says an implementation must provide memset, it will be there for you. Otherwise, it's not C.

Comment: IMO, POSIX did a mistake removing `bzero(3)`; it has a much better interface than `memset(3)`, as @MichaelBurr already noted in his answer.  However, not being in any standard shouldn't be important to user code.  One can use `bzero(3)` (and I'd encourage that), and if an implementation lacks it, just `inline void bzero(void *s, size_t n) { memset(s, 0, n); }` would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

For memset function, the second argument is an `int` and the third argument is `size_t`,

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

which is typically an `unsigned int`, but if the values like, `0 and 16` for second and third argument  respectively are entered in wrong order as 16 and 0 then,
such a call to memset can still work, but will do nothing. Because the number of bytes to initialize are specified as `0`.

```
void bzero(void *s, size_t n)
```

Such an error can be avoided by using bzero, because swapping the two arguments to bzero will always be caught by the C compiler if function prototypes are used.

Comment: Such an error can also be avoided with memset if you simply think of the call as "set this memory to this value for this size", or if you have an IDE that gives you the prototype or even if you just know what you're doing :-)

Comment: Agree, but this function was created at the time when such intelligent IDEs were not available for the support.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to mention something about bzero vs. memset argument. Install ltrace and then compare what it does under the hood.
On Linux with libc6 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6), the calls made are exactly the same (via `ltrace ./test123`):

```
long m[] = {0}; // generates a call to memset(0x7fffefa28238, '\0', 8)
int* p;
bzero(&p, 4);   // generates a call to memset(0x7fffefa28230, '\0', 4)
```

I've been told that unless I am working in the *deep bowels of libc* or any number of kernel/syscall interface, I don't have to worry about them. 
All I should worry about is that the call satisfy the requirement of zero'ing the buffer. Others have mentioned about which one is preferable over the other so I'll stop here.

Comment: This happens because some versions of GCC will emit code for  `memset(ptr, 0, n)` when they see `bzero(ptr, n)` and they can't convert it to inline code.

Comment: @zwol It's actually a macro.

Comment: @S.S.Anne gcc 9.3 on my computer does this transformation itself, without any help from macros in the system headers. `extern void bzero(void *, size_t); void clear(void *p, size_t n) { bzero(p, n); }` produces a call to `memset`.  (Include `stddef.h` for `size_t` without anything else that could interfere.)

Comment: @zwol And you've verified in that test that including `stddef.h` does not end up causing a `bzero` macro to be defined?

Comment: @mtraceur Yes. Also, I can reproduce the effect with no headers at all, using gcc's builtin `__SIZE_TYPE__`.  Also, `stddef.h` defining a macro named `bzero` would be a dire conformance violation.

Comment: @zwol Cheers, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** `memset` require more assembly operations then `bzero`.

This is the source:
http://fdiv.net/2009/01/14/memset-vs-bzero-ultimate-showdown

Comment: Yes, that is one thing that I mentioned in the OP.  I actually even linked to that exact page.  It turns out that doesn't seem to really make much difference due to some compiler optimizations.  For more details see the accepted answer by ouah.

Comment: This only shows that one rubbish implementation of memset is slow. On MacOS X and some other systems, memset uses code that is set up at boot time depending on the processor that you are using, makes full use of vector registers, and for large sizes it uses prefetch instructions in clever ways to get the last bit of speed.

Comment: fewer instructions doesn't mean faster execution. In fact optimizations often increase the binary size and number of instructions due to loop unrolling, function inlining, loop alignment... Look at any decent optimized code and you'll see it often has much more instructions than shitty implementations

Answer (score 0):

memset takes 3 parameters, bzero takes 2
in memory constrained that extra parameter would take 4 more bytes and most of the time itll be used to set everything to 0