# bzero() & bcopy() versus memset() & memcpy()

Tags: c, linux

Is there any reason to use the non-standard `bzero()` and `bcopy()` instead of `memset()` and `memcpy()` in a Linux environment? I've heard many say that they're better for Linux compilers, but haven't seen any advantages over the standard functions.

Are they more optimized than the standard ones, or do they have any behavioral particularity for which they're preferred?

Comment: There is exactly one place where `bzero` is "better" than `memset`: you can tail-call to `bzero` from a function which only takes 2 arguments even on architectures where each argument takes a stack slot. As for `bcopy`, I believe it's analogous to `memmove`, not `memcpy`.

Comment: `bcmp(), bcopy(), bzero(), ffs()` are **not** recommended for new applications where portability is important, they are provided solely for portability of BSD applications.

Comment: @Grijesh I know what they do, I wanted to know if anything was special on a deeper level

Answer (score 61, accepted):

While `bzero` and `bcopy` functions aren't ISO C (the actual standard that I assume you're talking about when referring to them as non-standard), they *were* a POSIX standard thing, although they pre-dated both ISO *and* POSIX.

And note that use of the word "were" - these functions were deprecated in POSIX.1-2001 and fianally *removed* in POSIX.1-2008, in deference to `memset`, `memcpy` and `memmove`. So you're better off using the standard C functions where possible.

If you have a *lot* of code that uses them and you don't want to have to go and change it all (though you probably *should* at some point), you can use the following quick substitutions:

```
// void bzero(void *s, size_t n);
#define bzero(s, n) memset((s), 0, (n))

// void bcopy(const void *s1, void *s2, size_t n);
#define bcopy(s1, s2, n) memmove((s2), (s1), (n))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <strings.h>
void bcopy(const void *src, void *dest, size_t n);
```

**Description**
The `bcopy()` function copies n bytes from src to dest. The result is correct, even when both areas overlap.

Conforming to:
4.3BSD, it seems **b** comes from BSD and it seems deprecated.

Which means `bcopy` is analogous to `memmove()` not `memcpy()` as R.. said at his comment.

Note: `strings.h` is also distinct from `string.h`.

Comment: BSD didn't put `b` prefixes on things to advertise their origin. Actually the `b` seems to stand for "byte". These functions are described as operating on "byte strings" (contrasted with null-terminated text strings) in this old man page: http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/man/man3/bstring.3

Answer (score 3):

Actually nowdays it could be the other way around. You see that because `memcpy` and `memset` is included in the standard the compiler will be allowed to assume that function called so does exactly what the standard prescribes. This means that the compiler can replace them with the most efficient way of performing the operation it can figure out. With `bcopy` and `bzero` on the other hand the standard does not prescribe any behavior on those so the compiler can't assume anything - which means that the compiler would need to issue an actual function call.

However GCC for example knows about `bcopy` and `bzero` if it's built for an OS that have them.

Comment: More precisely, some compilers (and notably recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) can handle `memcpy`, `memset`, `memcmp` in a "magic" way (conforming to standards), e.g. with GCC *builtins*, and can optimize them specially