# Assigning String to Hostent in C

Tags: c, sockets, compiler-errors, webserver

I am coding something to find web servers. It is in C.

I have this

```
sprintf(pre_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", num1, num2, num3, num4);
```

num1-4 is an ip like 1.1.1.1. This part works..

```
he = gethostbyname(pre_ip);
```

This should assign `struct hostent *he;` to the ip..

but this doesnt work..

```
server_info.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
//lol220
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_info;
    struct hostent *he;
    int socket_fd,num;
    char buffer[1024];

    char buff[1024];

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket Failure!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&server_info, 0, sizeof(server_info));
    server_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_info.sin_port = htons(80);

//-------------------------------looooop------------------------
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;
int num3 = 1;
int num4 = 1;
int done = 1;
char ip;
char pre_ip[256];
while(done){
        if(num4 == 256){
        num4 = 1;
        num3++;
        }
        if(num3 == 256){
        num3 = 1;
        num2++;
        }
        if(num2 == 256){
        num2 = 1;
        num1++;
        }
        if(num1 == 255 && num2 == 255 && num3 == 255 && num4 == 255){
        done = 0;
        }
        // MOST LIKELY NON WORKING PART 
        sprintf(pre_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", num1, num2, num3, num4);
        printf("%s\n", pre_ip);
        he = gethostbyname(pre_ip);
        server_info.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
            if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr))<0) {
                printf("Could not connect to %s", he);
            }
            else{
                printf("Could connect to %s", he);
            }
        // MOST LIKELY NON WORKING PART 

num4++;
}
return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine.

prints "1.1.1.1" then it says "Could not connect to 8T1.1.1.2" so that means `he == "8T1.1.1.2`.

Comment: A `hostent*` is not a `char*` so you cannot print the content of a `hostent` using `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the ip in this line:

```
printf("Could not connect to %s", he);
```

you cast `struct hostent` to `char *`, this leads the odd chars before the ip. Actually, it's fine to use the ip to connect the server directly, no need for `gethostbyname`. If you really want to try this function, just like this:

```
bzero(&server_info, sizeof(server_info));
const char *ip = inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr);
...
printf("Could not connect to %s", ip);
```

Comment: Or, instead of calling `inet_ntoa()`, just use the `pre_ip` buffer that was already formatted with the IP address beforehand

Comment: Indeed so. Maybe op just copied some code from somewhere and tried it:)

Comment: Please consider [not using `bzero()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331555/2171689). The [`bzero()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html) function was deprecated in POSIX.1-2001 and removed in POSIX.1-2008. Use [`memset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_info;
    int socket_fd;

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket Failure!!\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    memset(&server_info, 0, sizeof(server_info));
    server_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_info.sin_port = htons(80);

    for (uint32_t ip = 0x01010101; ip != 0xFFFFFFFF; ++ip) {
        server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip);
        printf("Connect to %s: ", inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr));
        if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, sizeof(server_info)) == -1) {
            printf("Failed\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Success\n");
            close(socket_fd);
            if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Socket Failure!!\n");
                exit(1);
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking argc?

Comment: Because it was in the original code, so I left it in, assuming the poster will use it later.  The only thing I changed was the connect loop.