# C memcpy copies bytes with little endianness

Tags: c++, c, pointers, endianness

I a writing a routine to append bytes to a byte_array like so

```
unsigned long speed = 0xfeb;
char byteArray[8];
bzero(byteArray,8); //fills every of the 8 bytes with zero
memcpy(byteArray,&speed ,4); //copies 4 bytes from speed to byteArray
```

After the operation i am expecting byteArray to have the value `0xfeb` but it turns out that byteArray has the value `0xebf`

What is happening ? is it normal for memcpy to force the result to little-endianness ? What should i do to get the result without the change of endianness ?

Comment: There's no specification. The endianess depends on your platform.

Comment: Also, `byteArray` should have `0xeb, 0x0f`.

Comment: The output is going to be in the system's endianness. If you want to control this, bit swap to the form you want. `__builtin_bswap32()` and others are available with all the compilers.

Comment: `memcpy` will blindly copy data from source to destination, how data is arranged in source and destination and how it is treated is depends on your platform.

Comment: It doesn't. It copies one byte after another, in the same order. Your diagnosis is erroneous.

Comment: 'Clear and precise' and wrong.

Comment: Why do you think that the endianness is changing?

Comment: @Vagish The answer is that the question is wrong.

Comment: @iBug There is a specification, and endianness is irrelevant to it.

Comment: OT: bzero was deprecated. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset

Comment: You should never use the `char` type to store raw bytes. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: "but it turns out that byteArray has the value 0xebf" --> this I find incredulous.  Did you mean " has the value  0xeb, 0x0f, 0x00,0x00"`?

Answer (score 11):

[`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) just copies bytes and doesn't care about endianness:

> Copies count bytes from the object pointed to by src to the object pointed to by dest. Both objects are reinterpreted as arrays of unsigned char.

If you're on a little-endian machine it will copy LSB first. On a big-endian machine it will copy MSB first, and you will get the expected `0x0f 0xeb`.

---

Unrelated, but you shouldn't use hard-coded values, but rather `sizeof`, e.g.

```
unsigned long speed = 0xfeb;
char byteArray[sizeof(speed)];
bzero(byteArray, sizeof(byteArray));
memcpy(byteArray, &speed , sizeof(speed));
```

Comment: Code comments need update or removal.  `fills every of the 8 bytes with zero` and `copies 4 bytes from speed to byteArray` are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` does exactly what it says on the tin: it copies memory. It does not mess about with the ordering of bytes.

Endianness is only relevant if you want to know how a particular bit pattern maps to the value of the integral type. Folk tend to blame endianness for all sorts of things: in the majority of occasions it has a benign effect, and that's the case here.